# Mesosphere slaves do not register

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I'm a novice in this area. I have configured 6 ubuntu machines (3 master and 3 slave) using instructions from mesosinaction.com.

When i access a master machine it says only one slave is registered, and refers to the host of the local machine slave (even though this should be disabled). I get redirected to the master machine if i try to connect to the wrong one. But when i start my slaves they immediately stop, Do not register to masters, and give errors. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Installation**

On master Nodes Mesos was installed using

```
apt-get install mesos zookeeperd
```

On slave nodes it was installed using

```
sudo apt-get install mesos
```

I have run the following scripts.

**Disable slave on masters**

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mesos-slave
```

**Configure Zookeeper**

run script with

```
export MESOS_zk=zk://10.18.89.11:2181,10.18.89.12:2181,10.18.89.13:2181/mesos
export MESOS_quorum=2
export MESOS_work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
export MESOS_log_dir=/var/log/mesos
```

edit zoo.cfg to contain

```
server.1=10.18.89.11:2888:3888
server.2=10.18.89.12:2888:3888
server.3=10.18.89.13:2888:3888
```

followed by

```
#> service mesos-master restart
```

On Slave Nodes I disable mesos master

```
#> echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mesos-master
```

run the following script

```
export MESOS_master=zk://10.18.89.11:2181,10.18.89.12:2181,10.18.89.13:2181/mesos
export MESOS_work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
export MESOS_log_dir=/var/log/mesos
```

followed by

```
#> service mesos-slave restart
```

**LOGS**
In /var/log/mesos i get the following files on the slave machine.

```
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7783
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7805
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7827
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7849
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7871
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7893
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7915
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7937
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7959
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.7981
mesos-slave.10-18-89-16.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132419.8003
mesos-slave.INFO
```

The mesos-slave.INFO contains the following.

```
Log file created at: 2016/01/22 13:24:19
Running on machine: 10-18-89-16
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0122 13:24:19.600344  8003 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0122 13:24:19.600586  8003 main.cpp:185] Build: 2015-10-12 20:57:28 by root
I0122 13:24:19.600600  8003 main.cpp:187] Version: 0.25.0
I0122 13:24:19.600607  8003 main.cpp:190] Git tag: 0.25.0
I0122 13:24:19.600613  8003 main.cpp:194] Git SHA: 2dd7f7ee115fe00b8e098b0a10762a4fa8f4600f
I0122 13:24:19.600814  8003 containerizer.cpp:143] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem,filesystem/posix
I0122 13:24:19.605336  8003 linux_launcher.cpp:103] Using /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer as the freezer hierarchy for the Linux launcher
I0122 13:24:19.613593  8003 main.cpp:272] Starting Mesos slave
I0122 13:24:19.614564  8019 slave.cpp:190] Slave started on 1)@10.18.89.16:5051
I0122 13:24:19.614586  8019 slave.cpp:191] Flags at startup: --appc_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/appc" --authenticatee="crammd5" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" --cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="mesos" --default_role="*" --disk_watch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --enforce_container_disk_quota="false" --executor_registration_timeout="1mins" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" --hadoop_home="" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --image_provisioner_backend="copy" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher_dir="/usr/libexec/mesos" --log_dir="/var/log/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --master="zk://localhost:2181/mesos" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --port="5051" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registration_backoff_factor="1secs" --resource_monitoring_interval="1secs" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --sandbox_directory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --strict="true" --switch_user="true" --systemd_runtime_directory="/run/systemd/system" --version="false" --work_dir="/tmp/mesos"
I0122 13:24:19.614917  8019 slave.cpp:354] Slave resources: cpus(*):2; mem(*):2929; disk(*):3867; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0122 13:24:19.615025  8019 slave.cpp:390] Slave hostname: mesosslave3
I0122 13:24:19.615037  8019 slave.cpp:395] Slave checkpoint: true
I0122 13:24:19.617189  8019 state.cpp:54] Recovering state from '/tmp/mesos/meta'
I0122 13:24:19.617219  8019 state.cpp:690] No checkpointed resources found at '/tmp/mesos/meta/resources/resources.info'
```

My Mesos Master logs Contains the following files.

```
mesos-master.10-18-89-11.invalid-user.log.INFO.20160122-132301.23030
mesos-master.10-18-89-11.invalid-user.log.WARNING.20160122-132301.23030
mesos-master.INFO
mesos-master.WARNING
```

with .INFO containing the following.

```
Running on machine: 10-18-89-11
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0122 13:23:01.562093 23030 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0122 13:23:01.562300 23030 main.cpp:229] Build: 2015-10-12 20:57:28 by root
I0122 13:23:01.562312 23030 main.cpp:231] Version: 0.25.0
I0122 13:23:01.562319 23030 main.cpp:234] Git tag: 0.25.0
I0122 13:23:01.562325 23030 main.cpp:238] Git SHA: 2dd7f7ee115fe00b8e098b0a10762a4fa8f4600f
I0122 13:23:01.562367 23030 main.cpp:252] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I0122 13:23:01.570297 23030 leveldb.cpp:176] Opened db in 7.861315ms
I0122 13:23:01.577780 23030 leveldb.cpp:183] Compacted db in 7.452531ms
I0122 13:23:01.577816 23030 leveldb.cpp:198] Created db iterator in 7011ns
I0122 13:23:01.577832 23030 leveldb.cpp:204] Seeked to beginning of db in 5688ns
I0122 13:23:01.577883 23030 leveldb.cpp:273] Iterated through 3 keys in the db in 42391ns
I0122 13:23:01.577913 23030 replica.cpp:744] Replica recovered with log positions 61 -> 62 with 0 holes and 0 unlearned
I0122 13:23:01.579000 23030 main.cpp:465] Starting Mesos master
I0122 13:23:01.579012 23049 log.cpp:238] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
I0122 13:23:01.579221 23047 recover.cpp:449] Starting replica recovery
I0122 13:23:01.579627 23045 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in VOTING status
I0122 13:23:01.579675 23045 recover.cpp:464] Recover process terminated
I0122 13:23:01.584900 23048 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(2)@10.18.89.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.584924 23048 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I0122 13:23:01.584934 23048 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.585255 23030 master.cpp:376] Master 831f97c5-0580-4cad-8113-06af4d461665 (mesosmaster1) started on 10.18.89.11:5050
I0122 13:23:01.585325 23030 master.cpp:378] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --log_auto_initialize="true" --log_dir="/var/log/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --quorum="1" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_store_timeout="5secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_reregister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos" --zk="zk://localhost:2181/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I0122 13:23:01.585500 23030 master.cpp:425] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I0122 13:23:01.585553 23030 master.cpp:430] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I0122 13:23:01.585608 23030 master.cpp:467] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W0122 13:23:01.585664 23030 authenticator.cpp:505] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I0122 13:23:01.585820 23030 authenticator.cpp:512] Initializing server SASL
I0122 13:23:01.586278 23045 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(1)@10.18.89.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.586302 23045 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0122 13:23:01.586313 23045 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.587795 23050 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(3)@10.18.89.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.589221 23050 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0122 13:23:01.589253 23050 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.593644 23043 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(4)@10.18.89.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.593667 23043 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0122 13:23:01.593852 23043 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.601426 23045 network.hpp:415] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I0122 13:23:01.601543 23045 group.cpp:674] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000040' in ZooKeeper
I0122 13:23:01.601898 23045 network.hpp:463] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@10.18.89.11:5050 }
I0122 13:23:01.602589 23046 master.cpp:1542] Successfully attached file '/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO'
I0122 13:23:01.602622 23046 contender.cpp:149] Joining the ZK group
I0122 13:23:01.604877 23043 contender.cpp:265] New candidate (id='39') has entered the contest for leadership
I0122 13:23:01.605916 23047 detector.cpp:156] Detected a new leader: (id='39')
```

And .WARNING containing

```
Log file created at: 2016/01/22 13:23:01
Running on machine: 10-18-89-11
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
W0122 13:23:01.585664 23030 authenticator.cpp:505] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting, and for reading Mesos in Action! I see a couple of small issues with the steps you performed, and hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

1. To disable a service in Ubuntu 14.04.x you should run

   ```
   echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mesos-slave.override
   ```

   Followed by

   ```
   sudo service mesos-slave stop
   ```

   The missing `.override` was an oversight on my part that was corrected during tech proofing. You should see it in the next (and final) MEAP version, as well as the final version of the book.
2. It looks like you're attempting to configure the Mesos masters and slaves using environment variables, but are using Mesosphere packages. Although this is generally possible to do with Upstart, I'd recommend using a file-based approach.

   For the Mesos master, try the following configuration:

   ```
   echo -n "zk://10.18.89.11:2181,10.18.89.12:2181,10.18.89.13:2181/mesos" > /etc/mesos/zk
   echo -n "2" > /etc/mesos-master/quorum
   echo -n "/var/lib/mesos" > /etc/mesos-master/work_dir
   echo -n "/var/log/mesos" > /etc/mesos-master/log_dir
   ```

   For the Mesos slave, try the following configuration:

   ```
   echo -n "zk://10.18.89.11:2181,10.18.89.12:2181,10.18.89.13:2181/mesos" > /etc/mesos/zk
   echo -n "/var/lib/mesos" > /etc/mesos-slave/work_dir
   echo -n "/var/log/mesos" > /etc/mesos-slave/log_dir
   ```

   Then restart each of the services.

That should get the Mesos masters and slaves configured properly and communicating with ZooKeeper, which I assume is already configured properly and serving clients.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers, I tried to reconfigure at the time using @rogers changes however i was still getting issues. I started again using the open.mesosphere.com for both masters and slaves and i now have a working cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In your slave logs I see that the master that the slave is try to connect to is the localhost.

--master="zk://localhost:2181/mesos"

You should follow the instructions [open.mesosphere.com](https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/#slave-setup) for the slave setup to setup the mesos slaves to connect to the right master. As @Roger pointed out you need to setup the zookeeper info in /etc/mesos/zk to tell the slaves about the masters.